# Timing Fragment Transitions - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, kotlin, transition

I'm building an Android application and in one section there's a list of card fragments I've made that load into the screen. These fragments use the fragment manager transitions to enter from the right however they do so all at once. I want to make them enter sequentially as it feels more natural however I can't figure out how. Code posted below.

```
fun updateResultsActivity() {
    // Add fragments to container
    for (i in 0 until placesList.size) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_from_right, R.animator.exit_to_left)
                .add(R.id.layout_container, fragmentList[i]).commit()
    }

    updateShowMoreButton()
}
```

I've tried adding sleep() lines, making the function add only one fragment and putting said function in a loop, and others and nothing seems to work. Any advice is welcome so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's desired behavior, but you can create Handler associated with main looper when initializing your UI component, and then you can post delayed runnable with fragment transactions.

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

for (i in 0 until placesList.size) {
    handler.postDelayed({
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_from_right, R.animator.exit_to_left)
            .add(R.id.layout_container, fragmentList[i]).commit()
    }, 1000*i)
}
```